# Pyridinium ion in inositol nicotinate

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, biochemistry, chemical-biology, esters

I have read about inositol nicotinate which is used as a medication for deficiency in vitamin B-3. I think that if acetic acid was applied to this medication it would form pyridinium ion and acetate ion, but I don't know if the acetic acid will react with inositol in a transesterification reaction, and form nicotinic acid and ionsitol acetate, so if the latter happens how could I prevent it and push the reaction towards the first route?

Comment: First of all, why you want to make a acetate salt of inositol hexanicotinate? Well, if things happens as you suggested, both nicotinic acid and expected inositol hexanicotinate$\ce{.6CH3CO2H}$ would disolve in aqueous medium while trans-esterated product would dissolve in only organic solvents. So, you may able to remove unwanted byproduct by solvent extraction.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne then I should react acetic acid with inositol hexanicotinate in organic solvent and then collect nicotinic acid and inositol hexapyridinium hexaacetate using water ?But I think  more nicotinic acid would be produced than the desired product. I want to push the reaction towards making inositol hexapyridinium hexaacetate. Note: inositol hexanicotinate is insoluble in water

Comment: Sounds like a plan.